# HtmlAgilityPack Save Process Not Letting Go Of File

Tags: c#, process, html-agility-pack

I am saving some of the rendered html of a web site by overriding the Render method and using HtmlAgilityPack.  Here is the code:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter()))
    {
        base.Render(htmlwriter);
        string output= htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(output);
        doc.Save(currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\dashboardTable.html");
    }
}
```

However, some process does not let go of the saved file and I am unable to delete it from the server.  Does anyone know of an HtmlAgilityPack issue that would cause this?

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT:

I have tried both of the methods suggested.  I can't tell if they are the solution yet because my app is frozen on the server due to the files I can't delete.  However, when I use these solutions on my own machine, the rendered HTML does not save as an HTML table anymore but rather like this:

```
INCIDENT MANAGEMENT
Jul '12     F'12
Trend   F'12    2011
(avg)
Severe Incidents (Sev1/2):  3       2.1 4.16
Severe Avoidable Incidents (Sev1/2):    1       1.3 1.91
Incidents (Sev3):   669     482 460.92
Incidents (Sev4) - No business Impact:  1012        808 793
Proactive Tickets Opened:   15      19.3    14
Proactive Tickets Resolved/Closed:  14      17.3    11
CHANGE MANAGEMENT
Total Planned Changes:  531     560 583.58
Change Success Rate (%):    99.5        99.4    99
Non-Remedial Urgent Changes:    6       11  47.08
PROBLEM MANAGEMENT
New PIRs:   2       1.4 2
Closed PIRs:    0       2   3
Overdue Action items:   2       3.2 0
COMPLIANCE MEASUREMENTS
    Jul Trend   Jun
Total Number of Perimeter Devices:  250     258
Perimeter Devices - Non Compliant:  36      31
Total Number of Internal Devices:   6676        6632
Internal Devices - Non Compliant:   173     160
Unauthorized Perimeter Changes: 0       0
Unauthorized Internal Changes   0       0
LEGEND

ISP LINKS
July    June    Trend
SOC CPO DRP SOC CPO DRP
40% 34% 74%     39% 35% 74%     
BELL MPLS HEAD ENDS
July    June    Trend
SOC CPO SOC CPO
8%  5%  7%  10% 8%  5.5%    7%  10% 
ENTERPRISE NETWORK (# of issues called out)
July    June    Trend
CORE    FW/DMZ  CORE    FW/DMZ
1       0       1       0   
US & INTL (# of issues called out)
July    June    Trend
US  Intl    US  Intl
2   2   2   3   
LINE OF BUSINESS    BELL WAN MPLS
<>  50%-65% >65%    <>  50%-65% >65%    Trend
Retail: 2272    0   1   2269    4   0   
Business Banking:   59  1   0   60  0   0   
Wealth: 122 2   0   121 2   1   
Corporate:  51  0   0   49  2   0   
Remote ATM: 280 0   0   280 0   0   
TOOLS
Version Currency    Vulnerability Status    Health Status
Key Messages:
```

where only the text data has been saved and all of the HTML and CSS is missing.  If I just use doc.Save() I get an exact representation of the table as it displays on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Per @L.B's comments it appears that HtmlAgilityPack does use a `using` block as in my example so it will be ensuring that the stream gets closed.

Thus as I suggested at the end of my original answer this must be a server environment problem

**Original Answer**

This may be some sort of bug with HtmlAgilityPack - you may want to report it to the developers.

However to eliminate that possibility you may want to consider explicitly controlling the creation of the `StreamWriter` for the file so you are explicitly closing it yourself.  Replace this line:

```
doc.Save(currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\dashboardTable.html");
```

With the following:

```
using (StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\dashboardTable.html"))
{
  doc.Save(fileWriter);
  fileWriter.Close();
}
```

If the issue still persists even with this change then that would suggest an issue with your server environment rather than an issue with HtmlAgilityPack.  Btw to test if this change makes a difference you should start from a clean server environment rather than one where you are already having issues deleting the file in question.

Comment: Wow, same answer 13 seconds apart?

Comment: HtmlDocument.Save closes the stream.

Comment: @L.B From what I could see in the source code it doesn't use a `using` block or `try catch` however which means the stream won't be closed if the internal implementation of `Save()` throws an exception.  Of course I could have looked at the wrong part of the code so please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @RobV as `File.WriteAllText` doesn't require an explicit dispose or close, it is all handled in the method

Comment: @L.B Where does the source for HAP live these days?  Using SVN browse on the source code tree on Codeplex shows no `Save(String filename)` method on HtmlDocument in Trunk and shows such a method in the 2.0 branch with the following definition: `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false, GetOutEncoding());
            Save(sw);
            sw.Close();`

Comment: @L.B Ignore my previous comments, the `Save(String filename)` method was in a separate file with `HtmlDocument` defined as a `partial class` - my bad.  It does internally use a `using` block for the write

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. Maybe the Save method isn't closing the underlying stream.

```
using( FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite( currDir + "\\" + reportDir + "\\dashboardTable.html" ) ){
    doc.Save(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe? No need to make assumptions. A few lines of code would show that it actually closes the stream.